# ClickOnce application still running after uninstall

Tags: .net, clickonce

The ClickOnce uninstaller does not kill my application.  Is there a way I can close my app when it's uninstalled using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this that I know of, at least not through ClickOnce. It will just mark the files and remove them when you finally close the application.